# How to package iTwin with Electron

Tags: bentley-itwin

"How do I package my developed code into Electron when using the template provided by the itwin.js official documentation? I have tried electron-builder and Electron Forge but have not been successful."
"The template provided by the official website is:
https://github.com/iTwin/viewer/tree/master/packages/modules/desktop-viewer-react
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6QSE.png)
"I hope to receive some suggestions. Thank you."